# Optimizing this piece of MYSQL Code for better execution time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

This piece of mysql code

```
SELECT  id, value, LENGTH(stuffing)
FROM  t_limit ORDER BY id LIMIT 150000, 10
```

can be optimized for better performance by rewriting it like this

**Note:Table has Index on Id**

```
SELECT  l.id, value, LENGTH(stuffing)
FROM    (
    SELECT  id
    FROM    t_limit
    ORDER BY
            id
    LIMIT 150000, 10
    ) o
JOIN    t_limit l
ON      l.id = o.id
ORDER BY
    l.id
```

**Ref:http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/**

Now how to optimize this piece of code in a similar way

```
SELECT  id, value, LENGTH(stuffing)
FROM  t_limit where value>100 ORDER BY id LIMIT 150000, 10
```

Comment: Did you try to just put the `where` clause in the subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea behind the optimization presented in the mentioned post is to query only the index pages without touching data pages. If you look at the query plan of the non-optimized query:

```
SELECT  id, value, LENGTH(stuffing) AS len
FROM    t_limit
ORDER BY
        id
LIMIT 150000, 10
```

it would be:

```
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t_limit | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 200000 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
```

So it's a simple table-scan. With the subquery optimization we receive:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------+---------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys                 | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------+---------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |     10 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | l          | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY | 4       | o.id |      1 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t_limit    | index  | NULL                          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 150010 | Using index                     |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------+---------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

Look at the `key` column which shows that the inner most statement used the PRIMARY index. I slightly modified your query so the value type is compatible:

```
SELECT  l.id, value, LENGTH(stuffing) AS len
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    t_limit
        where value like 'Value 1%'
        ORDER BY
                id
        LIMIT 30000, 10
        ) o
JOIN    t_limit l
ON      l.id = o.id
ORDER BY
        l.id
```

You need to consider what the `where` condition does. If you placed it in the outer query you would filter only the 10 rows returned from the inner query - I suppose that it was not what you were asking for. Now in the presented case (the `where` condition in the inner statement) you will end up with a table scan as there is no index that could fulfill your query:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |     10 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | l          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | o.id |      1 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t_limit    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 200000 | Using filesort                  |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

To profit from the same optimization as presented in the blog post you would need an additional non-clustered index, eg.

```
create index NCIX_t_limit_id_value on t_limit(id, value)
```

Now, when you run the above query the plan would be:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys                 | key                   | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                          | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL |    10 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | l          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,NCIX_t_limit_id_value | PRIMARY               | 4       | o.id |     1 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t_limit    | index  | NULL                          | NCIX_t_limit_id_value | 66      | NULL | 30010 | Using where; Using index        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

And again we are only scanning index pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query as:

```
SELECT l.id, value, LENGTH(stuffing)
FROM (SELECT  id
      FROM t_limit
      WHERE value > 100
      ORDER BY id
      LIMIT 150000, 10
     ) o JOIN
     t_limit l
     ON l.id = o.id
ORDER BY l.id
```

However, this will *not* improve performance.  MySQL has to read the data pages to get the rows with the correct value.

There are other indexes you can put on this:  (value), (value, id) and (id, value).  These will have different effects on performance.

The first will use the index to satisfy the `WHERE` clause and then basically ignore the "id" part of the index.  This will improve performance if `value > 100` is highly selective (say, fewer than 1% of the records meet this criterion).

The second might help.  To be honest, I don't know if MySQL will read the ids from the index and then do the sort.  Or, if it will read the original data.  If the first, this will help.

The third might be the best option.  I think MySQL will read the index looking for the values that match, and then use the index for the sort and limit.  I mean, it should, but I'm not 100% sure that the engine will actually do this.